# Powershell backreference within lookbehind

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm about to match lines which contain certain string twice.
The whole content is as below, I saved it to 1.txt file.

```
    &nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color="#5b4636">mit ~ und <u>Kegel</u></font></b> <span class="Icon">hum</span> <span class="Icon">fam</span> with the whole family;<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color="#5b4636">aus ~ern werden <u>Leute</u></font></b> <span class="Icon">prov</span> children grow up [all too] quickly;<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color="#5b4636">das ~ muss einen <u>Namen</u> haben</font></b> it must be called something;<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color="#5b4636">das ~ beim [rechten] <u>Namen</u> nennen</font></b> to call a spade a spade;<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color="#5b4636">~er und <u>Narren</u></font></b> [<i><font color="black">o</font></i> <b><font color="#5b4636"><u>Betrunkene</u></font></b>] <b><font color="#5b4636">sagen die Wahrheit</font></b> (<i><font color="black">sagen die Wahrheit</font></i>) children and fools speak the truth <span class="Icon">prov</span><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color="#5b4636">kleine ~er, kleine <u>Sorgen</u>, große ~er, große Sorgen</font></b> (<i><font color="black">große ~er, große Sorgen</font></i>) children when they are little make parents fools, when great, mad [<i><font color="black">or</font></i> they are great they make them mad] <span class="Icon">prov</span><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color="#5b4636">kein ~ von <u>Traurigkeit</u> sein</font></b> <span class="Icon">sein</span> to be sb who enjoys life;<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color="#5b4636">ich bin kein ~ von Traurigkeit</font></b> I [like [<i><font color="black">or</font></i> know how] to] enjoy life;<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color="#5b4636">ein ~ seiner <u>Zeit</u> sein</font></b> to be a child of one's time;<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color="#5b4636">[ein] <u>gebranntes</u> ~ scheut das Feuer</font></b> once bitten, twice shy <span class="Icon">prov</span><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color="#5b4636">was Glücksspiele angeht, bin ich ein gebranntes ~!</font></b> I've learned my lesson as far as games of chance are concerned;<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color="#5b4636">bei jdm <u>lieb</u> ~ sein</font></b> <span class="Icon">fam</span> to be sb's favourite [<i><font color="black">or</font></i> blue-eyed boy] [<i><font color="black">or</font></i> girl];<br>
```

My code to match strings is:

```
$content = Get-Content "D:\1.txt" -Encoding UTF8
foreach ($line in $content) { $line -match "(?<=$($Matches[1]).*)\(<i><font color=`"black`">([^<]*)</font></i>\)"}

False 
False 
False 
False 
False 
True  
False 
False 
False 
False 
False 
False
```

It returns true only in line6. If I match it without the lookbehind part however, it returns true in both line5 & 6.

```
foreach ($line in $content) { $line -match "\(<i><font color=`"black`">([^<]*)</font></i>\)"}
False
False
False
False
True
True
False
False
False
False
False
False
```

So what's wrong with my first regex code? I'm using Powershell 5.1.

Comment: @mklement0 I've tested _backreference within lookbehind_ with Regexbuddy (Powershell regex engine) and Powershell terminal, it works fine in Regexbuddy with exactly the content I posted above and a simple string with Powershell terminal which also works. Powershell is capable of this feature.

Comment: Yeah, I see your point. However, if the `$Matches` variable contains the result of the previous matched result (matched in line5) it cannot be true in line6.

Comment: @mklement0 1) It returns only the match with line6. 2)In my case, line6 matched successfully with `$Matches` included.

Comment: @mklement0 Wow!!! Thanks! It turns out that you're right, it returns true only in line5 this time after `Remove-Variable`, then I put the command in the loop to remove `$Matches` in every iteration. Now it returns true in both line5 & 6!

Comment: Glad to hear it, but I don't think it's working: with `$Matches` removed, the expandable strings referencing `$Matches[1]` should report an _error_ (`cannot index into null array`, though it's possible to suppress that) and `$Matches[1]`  evaluates to the _empty string_, which always matches. As noted before, when `$Matches[1]` _does_ have a value, it is that of the _most recent_ match that _succeeded_. If you remove `$Matches` in _every iteration_, the lookbehind assertion is effectively _ignored_ - no duplicate checking occurs.

Comment: That it doesn't work may not be obvious, because lines 5 & 6 are the only ones that match the phrase-finding part _by itself_. You can see the problem if you duplicate one of these lines and remove the duplicate phrase from it: your code will match that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, while the [.NET regex engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) - which PowerShell provides access to - does allow use of [backreferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/backreference-constructs-in-regular-expressions) (e.g, `\1`) in [lookaround assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) in principle, it doesn't seem to work in your scenario, which boils down to this simplified example:

```
# !! Does NOT match, even though 'foo foo' -match '(?<=foo )(foo)' does
PS> 'foo foo' -match '(?<=\1 )(foo)'
False
```

<sup>*Presumably*, the backreference in the lookbehind pattern is matched *before* the capture group and therefore doesn't match anything (a backreference to a capture group that hasn't (yet) captured anything never matches); a contrived example where it *does* work (capture group comes first):

`'foo foo' -match '(foo) .*(?<=\1)$'`</sup>

Therefore, your attempt (which mistakenly uses `$Matches[1]`<sup>[1]</sup> instead of `\1`) does not work.

You can work around this by performing *two* matching operations per line: the first to capture the phrase of interest, and the second to also look for that phrase in the string that comes before the initial match (note that the assumption is that there's only *one* match per line for the phrase-finding regex).

```
# Array of input lines.
$lines = @'
&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color="#5b4636">mit ~ und <u>Kegel</u></font></b> <span class="Icon">hum</span> <span class="Icon">fam</span> with the whole family;<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color="#5b4636">aus ~ern werden <u>Leute</u></font></b> <span class="Icon">prov</span> children grow up [all too] quickly;<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color="#5b4636">das ~ muss einen <u>Namen</u> haben</font></b> it must be called something;<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color="#5b4636">das ~ beim [rechten] <u>Namen</u> nennen</font></b> to call a spade a spade;<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color="#5b4636">~er und <u>Narren</u></font></b> [<i><font color="black">o</font></i> <b><font color="#5b4636"><u>Betrunkene</u></font></b>] <b><font color="#5b4636">sagen die Wahrheit</font></b> (<i><font color="black">sagen die Wahrheit</font></i>) children and fools speak the truth <span class="Icon">prov</span><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color="#5b4636">kleine ~er, kleine <u>Sorgen</u>, große ~er, große Sorgen</font></b> (<i><font color="black">große ~er, große Sorgen</font></i>) children when they are little make parents fools, when great, mad [<i><font color="black">or</font></i> they are great they make them mad] <span class="Icon">prov</span><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color="#5b4636">kein ~ von <u>Traurigkeit</u> sein</font></b> <span class="Icon">sein</span> to be sb who enjoys life;<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color="#5b4636">ich bin kein ~ von Traurigkeit</font></b> I [like [<i><font color="black">or</font></i> know how] to] enjoy life;<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color="#5b4636">ein ~ seiner <u>Zeit</u> sein</font></b> to be a child of one's time;<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color="#5b4636">[ein] <u>gebranntes</u> ~ scheut das Feuer</font></b> once bitten, twice shy <span class="Icon">prov</span><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color="#5b4636">was Glücksspiele angeht, bin ich ein gebranntes ~!</font></b> I've learned my lesson as far as games of chance are concerned;<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color="#5b4636">bei jdm <u>lieb</u> ~ sein</font></b> <span class="Icon">fam</span> to be sb's favourite [<i><font color="black">or</font></i> blue-eyed boy] [<i><font color="black">or</font></i> girl];<br>
'@ -split '\r?\n'                                                                            #'


foreach ($line in $lines) {
  # Note: To better illustrate the result, the doubled phrase
  #       rather than a Boolean is printed.
  if (
    $line -match '(?<before>.*)\(<i><font color="black">(?<phrase>[^<]+)</font></i>\)' 
      -and 
    $Matches.before -match [regex]::Escape($Matches.phrase)
  ) {
    $Matches[0]
  }
}
```

The above yields (matches on line 5 an 6 with doubled phrases):

```
sagen die Wahrheit
große ~er, große Sorgen
```

---

[1] The [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches) in PowerShell is populated *after* a regex operation to reflect what was captured, and is only populated if matching *succeeded*. It is purely a PowerShell feature that the .NET regex engine (which `-match` calls behind the scenes) knows nothing about.

By embedding `$($Matches[1])` in an *expandable string* (`"..."`) that serves as the regex, you're therefore (a) *expanding* that value (replacing the variable reference with its value) *before* the regex engine sees the string, and (b) are referencing what the most recent *previous* successful matching operation captured in its first capture group.

In short: the only way to use backreferences in PowerShell is to use the .NET regex engine's syntax; e.g., `\1` to refer to the first capture group.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your code is much better than mine, I'm merely a beginner in Powershell. By the way, is there a way to check the whole line being matched as a result?

Comment: My pleasure; glad to hear it helped. I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but in case you simply want the matching lines _in full_ returned, output `$line` instead of `$Matches[0]` in the `if` statement body.

Comment: Why not use `(?<=(foo)) \1`? Btw it doesn't work the other way around because `foo` can't be captured _before the expression is matched_ and the expression won't match _because `\1` hasn't been captured yet_

Comment: Thanks, @MathiasR.Jessen - it is what I suspected, but I couldn't find documentation for it; do you know of any, or have you looked at the source code? That `'foo foo' -match (?<=(foo)) \1` works certainly supports your explanation. However, this approach is not an option in this case, because what to match inside the lookbehind assertion isn't known in advance, it requires matching of a later string identified by its surrounding text.

Comment: To put it differently, @Mathias: There are two conceivable strategies for handling lookbehinds: (a) match the pattern first, then look _back_ for the lookbehind; (b) match the lookbehind first, then look for the pattern after it; it seems that (b) is used by the .NET regex engine, but it would be good to have confirmation, also so we don't miss potential other subtleties.

Comment: @mklement0 A bit vague, but [from learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/backreference-constructs-in-regular-expressions#what-backreferences-match): "A backreference refers to the most recent definition of a group (the definition **most immediately to the left**, when matching left to right)" - nothing's been captured to the left of either at any time

Comment: Further cemented by observing `[regex]::Match('foo foo','(?<=\1) (foo)',[System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::RightToLeft)` :)